# Elequent / Illuminate Laravel Database LIKE operation not working

Tags: laravel

I'm using the Illuminate database manager from Laravel, which works pretty good except using the `LIKE` operation for now.

I have tried those options but got nothing:

```
function initConnection()
{
    $capsule = new Capsule;

    $capsule->addConnection([
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => $this->config['host'],
        'database'  => $this->config['database-name'],
        'username'  => $this->config['username'],
        'password'  => $this->config['password'],
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => ''
    ]);

    $capsule->setAsGlobal();
}
```

And after initializing I tried:

```
function searchByName($word) 
{
    return Capsule::table($table)
        ->get()
        ->where('name', 'LIKE', '%'.$word.'%')
        ->first();
}

echo searchByName('John');
```

I also tried this option:

```
Capsule::table('table_name')
    ->select('SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE table_name.name LIKE "%John%"');
```

this also failed.

I can't find a documentation for using all the operations in Laravel.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to define the table in eloquent like this. your model will do that by itself if you follow the name convention or u can set table name in the model by :

```
class YourModelName extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'your_table_name';
}
```

now query like this :

```
function searchByName($word) {
     return Capsule::where('name', 'LIKE', '%'.$word.'%')->get();
}
```

this will return multiple value which will match the string.